# Excel vlookup versus address

Tags: excel

I am having a slight problem with my code I was able to get my formula to return the address of the cell in another sheet I need but it's currently just returning the address of the cell i need the actual value of that cell. It also doesn't return the sheet number.

Here is the formula:
=address(match(B2,Sheet1!C:C,0),34)
This returns $AH$1418

To get the proper value is need Sheet1!AH$1418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$AH:$AH,match(B2,Sheet1!C:C,0))
```

Comment: Intresting solution, makes sense, but gives a parse formula error.

Comment: sorry had a `;` in where `:` should be

Comment: Funny you just fixed it as I was editing your solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Cooper if this answered your question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.